# Is the set of regular points in a scheme open in general?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In the situation when smooth/k coincides with regularity (for a finite-type k scheme edit: k also perfect, thanks Remy), I think this should be true (?). But I am not sure about the situation for a general scheme.

Maybe there is a scheme consisting only of singular (non-regular) points? Oh, there is, I think: $k[x]/x^2$. But this doesn't answer my question about openness.

By regularity I mean that local ring is a regular local ring, i.e. the dimension of the Zariski tangent space is the same as the dimension of the local ring.

Comment: Two remarks: (1) For $X$ a variety over a field $k$, it is not true that the smooth points and the regular points coincide. This is only the case if $k$ is perfect. (2) Any localisation of a regular local ring is again regular. Thus, the regular locus is closed under generisation. Unfortunately, this does not yet prove that it's open, but it would follow if we know for example that the regular locus is constructible.

Comment: And yes, for varieties over a perfect field $k$ you can use the Jacobian criterion to prove that the set of smooth points is open (although it could be empty, as you noted).

Comment: The regular locus is open for schemes of finite type over any field. In fact, quite a lot is known even in the case where the base is not Spec(k). See [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07R2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. According to this [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/339694) post, there is an example of an affine Noetherian integral scheme of dimension 1 whose regular locus is not open, see Exposé XIX of the volume "Travaux de Gabber" in Astérisque 363-364.

See comments by Remy and Rieux for nice sufficient conditions for the regular locus to be open.